# Continuity of two multiplied functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

I am doing trying to prove that $h(x)=(fg)(x)$ is continuous and just wanted to know if

$$(f(X_n))(g(Y_n))=h(Z_n)$$

Where $X_n$ , $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ are sequences, and $Z_n=(X_n)(Y_n)$

Comment: This is only true if all of the functions are linear.

Answer (score 0):

to prove that $h$ is continuous you only need one sequence $x_n$. You need to show that 
$$
x_n \to x \implies h(x_n) \to h(x)
$$
However, by continuity
 $$
f(x_n) \to f(x), g(x_n) \to g(x)
$$
so using the fact that for sequences products work, 
$$
h(x_n) = f(x_n)  g(x_n) \to f(x)g(x) = h(x)
$$

Comment: The thing with this problem is that Xn is not equal to Yn...

Comment: but if your objective is to prove continuity, it should be.